# Swift - Update/add/delete item on a table view with sections and source

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

**How can I update/add/delete an item on a table view with sections and its source?**

Im having issues when trying to update a cell. Sometimes it happens on delete and add too.

It seems that a problem on sections is triggering it.

1- Data is loaded from a JSON response from a server.

2 - This data is sorted alphabetically and sections based on the first letter from the name is created adding each client to its indexed letter.

Im adding to print-screens:

Before:

[image: initial list]

After:

[image: misplaced indexes]

I renamed 'Bowl' to 'Bowl 2' and it 'created' a new entry, keeping the old and new value. If I refresh (pull), it gets fixed.

Also, sometimes, it removes 'Abc MacDon' and after refreshing, it gets fixed.

```
class ClientsViewController:  UITableViewController {

var sortedFirstLetters: [String] = []
var sections: [[Client]] = [[]]
var tableArray = [Client]()
var client: Client?
var wasDeleted: Bool?
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

@IBOutlet weak var noClientsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var noClientsView: UIView!

@IBAction func unwindToClients(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ClientViewController,
        let client = sourceViewController.client,
        let wasDeleted = sourceViewController.wasDeleted {

        if(wasDeleted) {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                print("Delteted")
                tableArray.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
//                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                        // Deleting the row in the tableView
//                        if self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: selectedIndexPath.section) > 1 {
//                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
//                        } else {
//                            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
//                            indexSet.add(selectedIndexPath.section)
//                            self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
//                        }
//
//                    }
            }

        }
        else {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                // Update an existing client.
                tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
                //tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                print("update")
                print(tableArray)
            }
            else {
                // Add a client.
                tableArray.append(client)
                print("add")
            }
        }
        self.prepareData()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondScene = segue.destination as! ClientViewController
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail", let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let currentPhoto = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        secondScene.client = currentPhoto
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("add")
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
    }
}

@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    getClients()
}

}

extension ClientsViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClientsViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.backgroundView = nil
    noClientsLabel.text = ""
    getClients() //for only the 1st time ==> when view is created ==> ok ish
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if(self.tableArray.count > 0) {
        return sortedFirstLetters[section]
    }
    else {
        return ""
    }
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return sortedFirstLetters
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClientCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.city + " - " + item.province
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].count
}

func getClients() {
    print("called server")
    self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:-100), animated: true)

    makeRequest(endpoint: "api/clients/all",
                parameters: [:],
                completionHandler: { (container : ApiContainer<Client>?, error : Error?) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error calling POST on /getClients")
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    self.tableArray = (container?.result)!

                    self.prepareData()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if(self.tableArray.isEmpty)
                        {
                            self.noClientsLabel.text = "bNo Clients"
                            self.tableView.backgroundView?.isHidden = false
                            self.noClientsLabel.text = ""
                            print("all")
                        }
                        else{
                            print("nothing")
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    }
    } )
}

//sorts and makes the index
func prepareData() {
    let firstLetters = self.tableArray.map { $0.nameFirstLetter }
    let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

    self.sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
    self.sections = self.sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
        return self.tableArray
            .filter { $0.nameFirstLetter == firstLetter }
            .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    }
}

}
```

*Struct*

```
struct Client: Codable {
var client_id: Int!
let name: String!
let postal_code: String!
let province: String!
let city: String!
let address: String!

init(name: String, client_id: Int! = nil, postal_code: String, province: String, city: String, address: String) {
    self.client_id = client_id
    self.name = name
    self.postal_code = postal_code
    self.province = province
    self.city = city
    self.address = address

}

var nameFirstLetter: String {
    return String(self.name[self.name.startIndex]).uppercased()
}

}
```

code after some interaction with Hardik

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ClientsViewController:  UITableViewController {

    var sortedFirstLetters: [String] = []
    var sections: [[Client]] = [[]]
  //  var tableArray = [Client]()
    var tableArray : [Client] = [Client]()
    var client: Client?
    var wasDeleted: Bool?
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var noClientsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var noClientsView: UIView!

    @IBAction func unwindToClients(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ClientViewController,
            let client = sourceViewController.client,
            let wasDeleted = sourceViewController.wasDeleted {

            if(wasDeleted) {
                if let index = self.tableArray.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
                    item.client_id == client.client_id
                }) {
                    self.tableArray.remove(at: index)
                    print("Delteted")
                    // Find the client in the tableArray by the client id and remove it from the tableArray
                    // I am writing an example code here, this is not tested so just get the logic from here.
                    //self.tableArray.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
                }

            }
            else {
                if self.tableArray.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in
                    item.client_id == client.client_id
                }) {
                    //Find the item in the tableArray by the client id and update it there too
                    // I am writing an example code here, this is not tested so just get the logic from here.
                    //if let index = self.tableArray.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
                    //    item.id == client.id
                    //}) {
                    self.tableArray[index] = client
                    //self.tableArray.replace(client, at: index)
                    //}
                    print("update")
                    print(tableArray)
                }
                else {
                    // Add a client.
                    tableArray.append(client)
                    print("add")
                }
            }
            // Now update the sections Array and it will have all the correct values
            self.prepareData()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

//            if(wasDeleted) {
//                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
//                    print("Delteted")
//                    sections[selectedIndexPath.section].remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
//                }
//
//            }
//            else {
//                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
//                    // Update an existing client.
//                    sections[selectedIndexPath.section][selectedIndexPath.row] = client
//                    //tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
//                    print("update")
//                    print(tableArray)
//                }
//                else {
//                    // Add a client.
//                    tableArray.append(client)
//                    print("add")
//                    self.prepareData()
//                }
//            }
//
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//
//                self.tableView.reloadData()
//            }







//            if(wasDeleted) {
//                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
//                    print("Delteted")
//                    tableArray.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
////                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
////                        // Deleting the row in the tableView
////                        if self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: selectedIndexPath.section) > 1 {
////                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
////                        } else {
////                            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
////                            indexSet.add(selectedIndexPath.section)
////                            self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
////                        }
////
////                    }
//                }
//
//            }
//            else {
//                if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
//                    // Update an existing client.
//                    tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
//                    //tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
//                    print("update")
//                    print(tableArray)
//                }
//                else {
//                    // Add a client.
//                    tableArray.append(client)
//                    print("add")
//                }
//            }
//            self.prepareData()
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//
//                self.tableView.reloadData()
//            }

        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondScene = segue.destination as! ClientViewController
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail", let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let currentPhoto = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            secondScene.client = currentPhoto
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
            print("add")
        }
        else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }
    }

    @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        getClients()
    }

}

extension ClientsViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClientsViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
        noClientsLabel.text = ""
        getClients() //for only the 1st time ==> when view is created ==> ok ish
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if(self.tableArray.count > 0) {
            return sortedFirstLetters[section]
        }
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sortedFirstLetters
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClientCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.city + " - " + item.province
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    func getClients() {
        print("called server")
        self.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:-100), animated: true)

        makeRequest(endpoint: "api/clients/all",
                    parameters: [:],
                    completionHandler: { (container : ApiContainer<Client>?, error : Error?) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("error calling POST on /getClients")
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }
                        self.tableArray = (container?.result)!

                        self.prepareData()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if(self.tableArray.isEmpty)
                            {
                                self.noClientsLabel.text = "bNo Clients"
                                self.tableView.backgroundView?.isHidden = false
                                self.noClientsLabel.text = ""
                                print("all")
                            }
                            else{
                                print("nothing")
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                        }
        } )
    }

    //sorts and makes the index
    func prepareData() {
        let firstLetters = self.tableArray.map { $0.nameFirstLetter }
        let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

        self.sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
        self.sections = self.sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
            return self.tableArray
                .filter { $0.nameFirstLetter == firstLetter }
                .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the wrong datasource. You should edit or update the `sections` array not `tableArray`.

Change your code in `unwindToClients` here :

```
   if(wasDeleted) {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            print("Delteted")
            tableArray.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
        }
    }
    else {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing client.
            tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
            //tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            print("update")
            print(tableArray)
        }
        else {
            // Add a client.
            tableArray.append(client)
            print("add")
        }
    }
    self.prepareData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

with this :

```
    if(wasDeleted) {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            print("Delteted")
            sections[selectedIndexPath.section].remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
        }

    }
    else {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing client.
            sections[selectedIndexPath.section][selectedIndexPath.row] = client
            //tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            print("update")
            print(tableArray)
        }
        else {
            // Add a client.
            tableArray.append(client)
            print("add")
            self.prepareData()
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

To fix the incorrect section headers, try doing something like this:

```
    if(wasDeleted) {
        if let index = self.tableArray.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            item.id == client.id
        }) {
            print("Delteted")
            // Find the client in the tableArray by the client id and remove it from the tableArray
            // I am writing an example code here, this is not tested so just get the logic from here.
            //self.tableArray.remove(at: index)
        }

    }
    else {
        if self.tableArray.contains(client) {
            //Find the item in the tableArray by the client id and update it there too
            // I am writing an example code here, this is not tested so just get the logic from here.
            //if let index = self.tableArray.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            //    item.id == client.id
            //}) {
            //    self.tableArray.replace(client, at: index)
            //}
            print("update")
            print(tableArray)
        }
        else {
            // Add a client.
            tableArray.append(client)
            print("add")
        }
    }
    // Now update the sections Array and it will have all the correct values
    self.prepareData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you... on add, I got this: Use of unresolved identifier 'selectedIndexPath'... so, Im appending to tableArray. I dont know if it is correct. Also, table is not updating till a pull refresh. What would happen if on update if I change Bowl to Wowl?

Comment: Still need to pull refresh to change data after update/delete

Comment: Perfect! On delete, if it is the last item, the section headers remais there. On update, if i change bowl to mowl, it doesnt create the new section and mowl is under B

Comment: Okay the issue here is, the main data source is the `tableArray` but the operations you are doing are done on the `sections` array. So you have to update the `tableArray` and for that we will need to get the edited item from `sections` and find it in the `tableArray` and update the it there. Then `prepareData()` will do the job.

Comment: I cant start chat yet. I kinda understand what you said, but im new on swift... and im not sure how to do it yet. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @RenanAguiar Checkout the updated answer. I have added the logic and example codes.

Comment: Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: Client)' ==> im getting lost again

Comment: @RenanAguiar try the new code now. I have updated the answer.

Comment: On delete I added: self.tableArray.remove(at: index) ==> it deletes.

On update: Value of type '[Client]' has no member 'replace'. Should i Remove and append? it doesnt seem correct.

Comment: try self.tableArray[index] = client instead of that replace method.

Comment: i tried before and got: Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()'

Comment: removing and appending it again is also fine. try that.

Comment: it doesnt seem to be the correct way of doing it. Also, reloading the entire table.. i read something about not to do it.

Comment: well in your case, to update the section headers it is necessary to reload the tableview.

Comment: also assign type to tableArray like this : `var tableArray : [Client] = [Client]()` this might let you use the `replaceAt` method.

Comment: no.. there is no replaceAt and previous error still showing.

Comment: @RenanAguiar I have tried this logic in playground it is working fine. so you might be doing something incorrect. can you please show me what you have done and in which line this error is occurring?

Comment: i added it in the end of my question

Comment: @RenanAguiar you are doing it wrong my friend. You are not getting the index in the replace part. Uncomment the index part and it will solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry! It works! Thank you for the patience! I appreciate that!